# Можно ли писать разные классы в сервлете?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Какие минусы писать разные классы в сервлете? или лучше их отдельно где-то держать?

например:

```
    public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public class Class1{
     }
    public class Class2{
     }
    public class Class3{
     }

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

             Class1 p = new Class1();
             p.printText();
             request.setAttribute("p", p); 
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

             Class2 ps= new Class2();
             p.printText();
             request.setAttribute("ps", ps); 
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

             Class3 pw = new Class3();
             p.printText();
             request.setAttribute("pw", pw); 
             request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

        }
        }
```

Comment: один класс - отдельный файл. За исключением когда вам необходим вложеный класс, который будет использоваться только в связке с "основным"

Answer (score 0):

Ну, в приципе, можно написать всю программу в одном классе с [внутренними](http://www.quizful.net/post/inner-classes-java) классами. Минусов тут довольно много. Самый главный - читаемость. Поверьте, не так просто читать и разбирать файл с кодом в котором более 40к строк. Кроме того, вы больше не разделяете уровень доступа по пакетам и интерфейсам, что тоже очень неудобно. Очень не рекомендую так делать.